# Deleting post tags removes categories

Tags: posts, mysql, tags

I'm trying to remove old post tags from a few WP installs. In some instances, I have over 20k tags for a few thousand posts. I've tried the following code:

```
delete t.*,tt.*,tr.*
FROM wp_terms AS t
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tt
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr
WHERE tt.term_id = t.term_id
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
AND tt.count < 5
```

This is supposed to delete any tags that are used on less than 5 posts. After I run it, I noticed that a number of categories are deleted as well (taxonomy = 'category') and I'm stumped why? Anyone else managed to do this??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but the way the tables are setup, WordPress can re-use the same `terms` record (with the same `term_id`) within different taxonomies. That is, if you have a `post_tag` called `favorites` and you also have a `category` called `favorites`, it can well be that WP uses the same `terms` record for both and only diversifies them via the `term_taxonomy_id` table. There's obvious advantages to that.

So...if your query above finds the term as part of the query and deletes it, then if it is also used as a category, it disappears, too, because the term record is gone and the relationship cannot be drawn anymore.

As said, i haven't verified that WP is actually doing it that way, but it would explain your phenomenon.

Solution would be to only delete term if its id only appears in `tt.term_id` once. I'd recommend breaking up the query for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip - here is how it ended up and it seems to work a treat :)

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND count <= 5) and term_id not in (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'category')
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND count <= 5) and term_taxonomy_id not in (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'category')
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND count <= 5
```